# Accessing service list from webapplication using windows auth

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I built an web application that gets list of all the services on selected server. I enabled windows auth on the application. It works fine when I run from vs2010, but when I deploy the same code on my local machine IIS I get the error as shown below. I also tested the website from couple of different user machines they to get the same error. Any idea on how to fix this and what are the settings I need to use in IIS for this to happen. I have access to all the servers and users who tested the application also have access to those servers.

**Message:** `Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer ''. This operation might require other privileges.`

```
Inner Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied

Stack Trace:    at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GetDataBaseHandleWithAccess(String machineName, Int32 serviceControlManaqerAccess)
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GetDataBaseHandleWithEnumerateAccess(String machineName)
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GetServicesOfType(String machineName, Int32 serviceType)
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GetServices(String machineName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without more information - it sounds like the identity of application pool running your application does not have enough permissions to access SCM. If you are looking to use the credentials of the user that's authenticating with the web app, you'll need to use impersonation.

A couple of questions - are you using impersonation? Also, if you change the Identity for the Application Pool to an administrator (this is not a long term solution, just a test), does that resolve the error?

Comment: Yep it resolves it if i use the identity or the Application Pool to an administrator. But based on the windows auth i would like to do it. As i am diplaying all the servers in a dropdown and some users may have access to it and some dont. So it will be a security issue. How can i impersonate as the user who is accessing application. I have only there principal identity through app.

Comment: looks like this is just a web.config setting: <identity impersonate="true" />. more information located here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158

Comment: I made the change, then it prompted me to change mode to Classic from integrated on apppool. Performed the change but it failed again as before. I tried to impersonate using code as shown below but it still results in the same. System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext = null;
                    impersonationContext = ((System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity).Impersonate();